# How to strip from a string those which are not in the a-z and 0-9 range?

Tags: php, arrays, string, strip

I know a version of this but i'm looking for the simplest way?

```
$string = "HeLLo$ my222 name is zolee0802343134";
$string = strtolower($string);
$replacement  = range (a, z);
$replacement2 = range (0, 9);

//
What comes here?
// 

I want to get this ->
$string = "hello my name is zolee";
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output contain the digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex for simplicity.

```
$string = "HeLLo$ my222 name is zolee0802343134";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-z ]/i", "", $string);
```

http://codepad.org/eDmXrnYR

Comment: this is what i get :( -> eomy222nameiszolee0802343134

Comment: Ah. I just did what the title said (to strip all except alphabets/digits). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://codepad.org/3KuCG2yf

```
<?php

$string = "HeLLo$ my222 name is zolee0802343134";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z ]/", "", $string);

?>
```

Comment: The OP wants to lowercase the whole string.  Maybe the question was edited since you posted this?

Comment: @Ray look at the question. and look at the other answers. there is nowhere where the OP states that they want lowercasing

Comment: Well the question _title_ requests to keep a-z and 0-9 only.  The example code lowercases the whole string, and the OP says "I want to get this --> hello...." with the h lowercased.  I am going by what the OP _asked for_, not what the other answers say. :)